# Datanuclues With Hbase Not Working With Collections Via JPA

Tags: jpa, hbase, datanucleus

Has anybody any experience with HBase usage with Datanucleus via JPA. I'm struggling to get Datanucleus to fetch collections for me from the Datastore. Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Dependencies:
https://github.com/ravindranathakila/www.ilikeplaces.com/blob/master/pom.xml

persistance.xml:
https://github.com/ravindranathakila/www.ilikeplaces.com/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

orm.xml:(with or without didn't make a difference though)
https://github.com/ravindranathakila/www.ilikeplaces.com/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/orm.xml

The code works fine with OpenJPA and Apache Derby database, so I should say with respect to JPA, there are no big flaws.

Once again, some help or failure cases would be much appreciated!

Comment: pointers ? look at the log, post code, split things down to owner-child classes and demonstrate something, read up on object lifecycle and fetch groups. Is it persisted? is it in the DB? Plenty of things there and without doing some of that you're relying on people having a crystal ball

Comment: Tried all. Not working. Moving on to Kundera. Thanks for taking your time off to show I'm wrong :-)

Comment: You give no sample classes and persistence code so impossible for anyone to answer anything meaningful.

Comment: @NeilStockton did you check out the links? We're open sourced and all the code is download'able from Github. Nevertheless, Datanucleus was a wrong bet for us, for many reasons.

Comment: You expect people to go through your app for you to find some bit of persistence code somewhere and see what could be the issue? You've got the wrong idea of open source and stackoverflow; people offer their time to help when you express a simple question with all info. DataNucleus works great on all of my apps, one using HBase, and the other on RDBMS.

Comment: Some people do. I guess you come from a different culture :D

Answer (score 1):

The best approach in case you are using maven to build on datanucleus is to [download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/datanucleus/files/datanucleus-accessplatform/) the bundled libraries and give system paths to them(go for the HBase full bundle, and a release version). This will save a lot of your time resolving conflicts and missing jars.

Next comes enhancing the classes. This can be done as mentioned [here](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/enhancer.html). Try different approaches mentioned there if you keep hitting dependency issues (theoretically, you shouldn't be since you are using the downloaded libraries, unless there are version conflicts with different versions of the same file or HBase-Zookeeper versions)

While this does not solve the above problem, I'm endorsing the question with this answer to help others jump ahead in narrowing down issues pertaining to this.